# Allowing user to create manufacturers prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a prestashop 1.7 based shop, and I need to add custom code to let customers create their own manufacturers. This user group obviously can't access back office, so they should be able to insert in shop DB a new manufacturer.

Is it possibile? And how can I do it?

Comment: have you tried anything so far ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what are you doing this for, but the best way, in my vision, should be to create a module which would add a new field on a front-end of your shop and would allow a user to fill and save some field with his manufacturer name

Comment: I already have such a module. Problem is: if user find a manufacturer it already exists, then he can easily select it from a dropdown menu; if the manufacturer does not exists, he can't insert a new one. I can easily add a field for it, but what function, method, classes, should i call? How can i make them save this custom value to DB?

Comment: Everything depends on your module, you can create all necessary methods inside it(to handle users requests) and use a default manufacturer class to save it. The script would be like:"if a user has pressed some button and field with a new manufacturer name wasn't empty then create new manufacturer(for example with $manufacturer = new Manufacturer(); $manufacturer->name = gotten name; $manufacturer->add(); but I don't sure maybe some more fields are required for class Manufacturer, you can check it out in the class file (root/classes/Manufacturer.php))"

Comment: You certainly gave me much help; but i'm pretty sure i can't add this script directly in .tpl file. I don't know where to define it and how can i call it from module (tpl file)

Comment: You can't do this throught tpl, only via php